# Why is there a $A_{\varepsilon}\subseteq C$ such that $\nu(C\setminus A_{\varepsilon})<\varepsilon$?

Tags: measure-theory

> > Let $E$ be countably infinite. Suppose that $v$ is a probability measure on $E$ supported on $C\subseteq E$. Since $\nu(E)=\nu(C)=1$ for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a $A_{\varepsilon}\subseteq C$ which is finite such that $\nu(C\setminus A_{\varepsilon})<\varepsilon$.

My question is why there exists such a finite subset $A_{\varepsilon}$ of $E$ for $\varepsilon > 0$ arbitrary.

Of course I can choose a finite subset $A\subseteq C$ such that
$$
1=\nu(C)=\nu(C\setminus A)+\nu(A).
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $E$ is countable, there exists an enumeration $(c_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of $C$. Using the $\sigma$-additivity of the measure $\nu$, we find

$$1 = \nu(C) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \nu(c_n).$$

It follows from the very definiton of the convergence of series $\sum_n \nu(c_n)$ that for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$$\sum_{n=1}^N \nu(c_n) \geq 1- \frac{\epsilon}{2}. \tag{1}$$

For $$A_{\epsilon} := \bigcup_{n=1}^N c_n$$ we have $A_{\epsilon} \subseteq C$ and, by $(1)$,

$$\nu(C \backslash A_{\epsilon}) \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2} < \epsilon.$$

Comment: Thank you very much! My idea first was to use continuity of the measure but as I see one does not need that at all.

Comment: @Salamo The statement can be proved using the continuity of the measure, that's correct. In fact, the proof is very similar.